# 日本語に違和感: タグ入力欄にフォーカスがある時に表示されるヘルプ: タグの使い方

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

> タグの使い方
>
> タグとは、あなたの質問をよく似た他の質問と一緒に分類するキーワードまたはラベルのことです。
>
> ► 既存の人気の高いタグを使用し、できるだけ新しいタグを作成しない
>   ► 一般的な省略形を使用する
>   ► シノニムを含めない
>   ► ダッシュで複数の単語を組み合わせて 1 つの単語にする
>   ► 最大タグ数は 5 個、タグ 1 個の最大文字数は半角 25 文字
>   ► タグ文字:[a-z 0-9 + # - .]
>   ► スペース、セミコロン、またはコンマでタグを区切る
>   人気のあるタグ »

- 「シノニム」はあまり一般的でない
- 「タグ文字」: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]  だと日本語が使えないようにみえる

英語版

```
How to Tag
A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions.
► favor existing popular tags; avoid creating new tags
► use common abbreviations
► don't include synonyms
► combine multiple words into single-words with dashes
► maximum of 5 tags, 25 chars per tag
► tag characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]
► delimit tags by space, semicolon, or comma
popular tags »
```

Comment: 「シノニム」に違和感あったら、[専門用語](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflowの専門用語)のリストに追加してくれますか？実は日本語が使える為、開発者に制限を改めて確認します（例えば、「：」はだめみたいですが、漢字・カタカナ・ひらがな全体OKらしいです）

Comment: @jmac [シノニムは追加済み](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/143/30) でした。過去の自分に感謝

Comment: 結果的、[a-z 0-9 + # - .]は正しいですが、[a-z]と[0-9]は全角文字（ひらがな、カタカナ、漢字）を含めています。

Comment: 原文への追随により、現在はよりシンプルなメッセージになっています。現時点で問題はなさそうですので、この質問は完了とさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

> タグの使い方
>
> 適切なタグ（質問につけるラベル）を使うことで、質問の範囲をわかりやすくし、同じトピックの質問を検索しやすくすることができます。
>
> ✓ 既存のよく使われているタグを優先的に使い、タグを作り散らかさない
>   ✓ 省略形は一般的なものを使う
>   ✓ 重複する意味のタグはつけない
>   ✓ 複数の英単語からなるタグは、単語同士をスペースのかわりにハイフンでつなぐ
>   ✓ 質問一つにつきタグは5個まで、タグは半角25文字まで
>   ✓ タグに使える文字: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]
>   ✓ スペースまたはセミコロン、コンマを入力して次のタグへ
>
> 人気タグ一覧 »

- "A tag is a keyword or label..." の文は、使うメリットを前面に出した内容に変えました
- 「ハイフンでつなぐ」は対象を英単語に限定しました: 日本語の場合は助詞を入れるかそのまま続けるかになりそう